# For loop not iterating through all values in vector

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to sum the NA values per year of multiple time series. I have created a vector of just my dates that I am then comparing to a vector of both dates and ozone values. I have first created a for loop that iterates through all the dates of my dates vector to extract just the years. I am then comparing the years vector to the years in the vector of both ozone and date values (this is where my issue is) I then hope to put each year into a vector and sum the NA values. When I attempt to iterate through the years in the date ozone vector I have either created an infinite loop or only pulled the first variable.

I have tried several different methods to iterate the vector of both dates and times but am very stuck. The other things I have tried are listed below as well as my code:

```
totalNA <- c()
for (i in npsfiles[1]) {
  timeozone <- import(i, date="DATE", date.format = "%m/%d/%Y", header=TRUE, na.strings="-999")
  O3 <- c(timeozone$O3)
  tyr <- substr(timeozone$date, 1, 10)
  ozone <- O3
  names(ozone) <- tyr
  for (d in as.character(tyr)) {
    theyears <- format.Date(d, "%Y")
    print(theyears)
    for (y in length(ozone)) {
      if (names(ozone[y]) == theyears) {
      totalNA <- c(totalNA, ozone[y])}
      print(y)
      }
  }   
}
```

My issue is at the third for loop. I have also tried:

```
for (y in seq(1:length(ozone))
for (y in ozone)
for (y in names(ozone))
```

Here is some data:

```
ABBR            DATE         O3
BADL-VC 10/01/1987 02   -999
BADL-VC 10/01/1987 03   -999
BADL-VC 01/01/1989 10   12
BADL-VC 01/01/1989 11   13
BADL-VC 01/01/1989 12   14
```

Comment: What package is `import()`? Please include any library statements.

Comment: Import is open air, I think this is the only package that is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues concerning the third loop:

1. When setting a loop range, you need to set the beginning to end with colon. So `length(ozone)` should be `1:length(ozone)`. Otherwise you iterate on only the last ozone item.
2. The `names(ozone)` returns full date and not year. So you need to format those elements just as you did with `theyears`.

Consider the following adjustment of third loop:

```
for (y in 1:length(ozone)) {
    ozoneyear <- format.Date(names(ozone[y]), "%Y")
    if (ozoneyear == theyears) {
      totalNA <- c(totalNA, ozone[y])
    }
    print(y)
}
```

Comment: if ozone be like ozone<- c(3,5,2,7), is there a way to iterate in these values? it is possible in python but i dont know R. I couldnt achieve.